# Why does Git for Windows create repositories that I can't delete from a command line?

Tags: windows-10, git

I have freshly "Reset" installation of Windows 10. I installed the "Git for Windows" distribution of Git from https://git-scm.org/.

If I create a git repository in any way (whether `init` or `clone`), that repository can't be deleted from my file system with a command line prompt. I have to use Windows Explorer to do it.

Here's a sample session:

```
PS C:\Users\radix> mkdir foo


    Directory: C:\Users\radix


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        5/10/2018   5:46 PM                foo


PS C:\Users\radix> cd foo
PS C:\Users\radix\foo> git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/radix/foo/.git/
PS C:\Users\radix\foo> cd ..
PS C:\Users\radix> rm foo -Recurse
rm : Cannot remove item C:\Users\radix\foo\.git: You do not have sufficient access rights to perform this operation.
At line:1 char:1
+ rm foo -Recurse
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (.git:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
rm : Directory C:\Users\radix\foo cannot be removed because it is not empty.
At line:1 char:1
+ rm foo -Recurse
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\radix\foo:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotEmpty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

This is PowerShell running as my normal user. Even if I run Powershell as an administrator, the `rm -Recurse` command still fails in the exact same way. The only way I know of to delete this new `foo` directory is to do it via Windows Explorer, which doesn't even complain or prompt about permissions - it just silently deletes it with no problem.

I don't believe this is a PowerShell-specific issue, because a similar behavior happens in CMD:

```
C:\Users\radix>dir foo
 Volume in drive C is Blade
 Volume Serial Number is B83C-EF1B

 Directory of C:\Users\radix

File Not Found

C:\Users\radix>git init foo
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/radix/foo/.git/

C:\Users\radix>del foo
C:\Users\radix\foo\*, Are you sure (Y/N)? y

C:\Users\radix>dir foo
 Volume in drive C is Blade
 Volume Serial Number is B83C-EF1B

 Directory of C:\Users\radix\foo

05/17/2018  08:46 PM    <DIR>          .
05/17/2018  08:46 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  275,911,991,296 bytes free

C:\Users\radix>dir /a foo
 Volume in drive C is Blade
 Volume Serial Number is B83C-EF1B

 Directory of C:\Users\radix\foo

05/17/2018  08:46 PM    <DIR>          .
05/17/2018  08:46 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/17/2018  08:46 PM    <DIR>          .git
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  275,866,763,264 bytes free
```

The DEL command does not display any errors, but it fails to actually delete the repository.

It's important to note that the `rm` command does delete the *files* from the repository, including the files inside the `.git` directory. But it leaves the `.git` directory there.

It has been posited that the "hidden" nature of the `.git` subdirectory is causing a problem. Here is a transcript of my experimentation regarding that:

```
PS C:\Users\radix> git init foo
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/radix/foo/.git/
```

At this point, I open Windows Explorer and navigate to the `C:/Users/radix/foo` directory, and rename `.git` to `git`. I also right click on the `.git` directory and open the Properties dialog, noting that it does not have the "hidden" flag. I also navigate into the `git` directory and right-click-open-properties on several subdirectories and files, noting that none of them have the "Hidden" flag set.

And then I try to delete the directory from powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\radix> del foo

Confirm
The item at C:\Users\radix\foo has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue, all children
will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): a
del : Cannot remove item C:\Users\radix\foo\git: You do not have sufficient access rights to perform this operation.
At line:1 char:1
+ del foo
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (git:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
del : Directory C:\Users\radix\foo cannot be removed because it is not empty.
At line:1 char:1
+ del foo
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\radix\foo:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotEmpty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

I do notice that several of the folders in this hierarchy are marked as "Read-Only". Is that related?

So I have two questions: why can't I delete this folder, and why is git creating it in a way that it can't be deleted in the first place? If the problem is that the directories are read-only, why is git creating them as read-only?

Comment: Which error did you get when you are deleting directory from Command Prompt (CMD)? While I get the same error when deleting from PowerShell, I do not get any error when deleting it from CMD.

Comment: Further investigation show that issue is caused by the fact that `.git` directory is hidden and `Remove-Item` refuse to delete it, unless you specify `-Force` parameter.

Comment: I do not believe that the hidden nature of .git is affecting things at all. When I remove the "Hidden" attribute from .git (and all items recursively), and rename it to "git", the behavior is the same.

Comment: Did you try another folder except `C:\User\user_name`? Also try with git in cygwin (i.e. install cygwin, open cygwin setup, install git).

Comment: @Biswapriyo my question is specifically and intentionally about Git for Windows.  and yes, I've tried it in directories like ~/Documents and subdirectories of ~/AppData/Local.

Comment: I tried latest git-for-windows in my PC and it works well. I didn't see your issue.

Comment: @ChristopherArmstrong It does not matter if you believe this or not, but it is here in the [source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master@%7B2018-05-17%7D/src/System.Management.Automation/namespaces/FileSystemProvider.cs#L3081-L3099). And this is the only place, I can find, which can generate particular error message. So, does the error message change after you unhide the `.git` directory? Also you did not show the error message, which you get, when you use Command Prompt instead of PowerShell.

Comment: @PetSerAl hey, sorry about the lack of updates, I will edit the question with more details shortly.

Comment: You're using the wrong command in `cmd`... `del` only deletes files (and even then not recursively unless you `del /s`). Use `rmdir /s` instead.

Comment: Does `del foo -Recurse -Force` fail with same error? And as @Bob say, you need to use `rd /s` in Command Prompt to remove directory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll start by addressing the easier case: `del` in cmd will never do what you want, because it only removes *files*. Even then, without `/s` it won't recurse and will only remove files in the top-level directory.

So, for cmd, you should be using `rmdir /s` to recursively delete all files and folders. Add `/q` if you want to disable the confirmation prompt.

---

Now, PowerShell. `Remove-Item` (which is what `rm` and `del` alias to) with just `-Recurse` will not recurse into hidden directories, and will therefore not delete their contents. Which leads to your error - which is not a "permission denied" but rather a "directory not empty".

To get around this, you can pass the `-Force` parameter (equivalent to *nix `-f`). So `rm -r -force` or `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force` should work.

I'm not entirely sure how you're getting a non-hidden `.git` directory - GfW (admittedly an older 2.9.2) creates them as hidden for me. In cmd, run `attrib .git` to check if it's hidden. Once un-hidden, a `Remove-Item -Recurse` works without `-Force`.

Comment: Git for Windows is creating `.git` as hidden. In one of my transcripts I described how renaming it to `git` and ensuring it is non-hidden is not solving the problem in powershell. I added that section in response to some comments on my original question.

Comment: @ChristopherArmstrong Works for me after un-setting hidden... try again with just `Remove-Item -Recurse`. And try the `-Force` option without unsetting hidden.

Comment: I found the problem: it's not just that the `.git` directory has the `H` attribute, but also that the pack files in `.git/objects/pack` have the `R` (read-only) attribute. Once I remove those attributes as well, I can finally delete the git repo without passing `-Force`.